# Connecting to Remote Desktop manually

Tags: azure, rdp

**Cloud Services aka Hosted Services**

How do I connect to the remote desktop manually?  Clicking the connect button will always run mstsc with maximum display size.  I tried using the Url directly but keep getting a rejection.  The .rdp file that is sent during connect is something like:

```
full address:s:mytestapp-20120825.cloudapp.net
username:s:xxxxx
LoadBalanceInfo:s:Cookie: mstshash=WCFServiceWebRole1#WCFServiceWebRole1_IN_0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.  I right-click the rdp file and select Edit.

I wonder what's in the rdp file that makes it work.